# crm 2011 - Lookup: Relationship Name from Attribute name

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I'm attempting to, using the SDK/Programatically, retrieve lookup relationship information given an attribute name. Within CRM 2011 this is provided all on one screen (see below)

[image]

So, in summary I want the Relationship Name, given the attribute name. Assume that I know that the attribute IS a lookup. If anyone has any hints or tips they would be appreciated.

Kind regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get this by getting the metadata for the entity and then look at the relationships on the entity. Here is a quick example.

Ex:

```
var entityRequest = new RetrieveEntityRequest();
entityRequest.RetrieveAsIfPublished = false;
entityRequest.LogicalName = "account";
entityRequest.EntityFilters = EntityFilters.Relationships;

var entityResponse = serviceProxy.Execute(entityRequest) as RetrieveEntityResponse;

var relationship =
    entityResponse.EntityMetadata.ManyToOneRelationships.SingleOrDefault(
    r => r.ReferencingAttribute == "transactioncurrencyid");         

return relationship.SchemaName;
```

This will give you transactioncurrency_account in the SchemaName of the relationship

Comment: Almost perfect, it needs to be the ReferencingAttribute that is tested, but apart from that all good. Many thanks.

Comment: @Ash Close, but no cigar then ;) edited the code sample with your input, so it is correct